# Tasker: If variable - not connected to Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, tasker, automation

I want my display brightness only to rise if **not** connected to any Wifi network (doesn't mean Wifi has to be turned off) but I can't figure out how exactly the Wifi variables work. The official documentation is very general and technical.

Edit: The problem is that my Wifi is instable which means Android doesn't have Wifi for about 2-3 seconds and then catches it back. So I added a 5 seconds `Wait` Action so that my display brightness doesn't change every 15 minutes but it happens anyway, only now 5 seconds later.

I think to finally make it work a "If variable" is necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way.

Go to Profiles → (New profile) → State →  Net →  Wifi Connected. Leave `SSID` blank and tick "Invert". Link this profile to a task which changes brightness.

Edit - Okay, I think I've found the solution. In the task which changes brightness, do this:

1. `Wait` for 5 seconds
2. `if %WIFII` (matches regex) `\bSCAN\b`

   - (Increase brightness)

Explanation: The `%WIFII` (WiFi info) variable not only gives the name of the WiFi that you are connected to, but also miscellanous information such as Mac and IP address and contains the phrase ">>> CONNECTED <<<". If you are not connected to any particular WiFi, it lists all of the WiFis available along with the phrase ">>> SCAN <<<".

The above task basically

1. Waits for 5 seconds (adjust accordingly!)
2. Checks if the `%WIFII` variable contains the word "SCAN" by means of a regular expression

   - If it contains "SCAN" it means that the device is NOT connected to a specific WiFi (if was connected, it would have the word "CONNECTED" in it).
3. Increases brightness accordingly

Note: Might cause problems if there are WiFis with the word "SCAN" in them! You can always change the `if` condition to something else such as `if %WIFII (doesn't match regex) \bCONNECTION\b`, or make it more specific for the phrase ">>> SCAN <<<" (I'm still new to regular expressions so I've no idea how to do it).

Comment: I already did that. I updated the question.

Comment: @Yethat So basically you want the brightness to increase if you are outside, however not when you're inside but disconnected to the unstable WiFi? I think I have a solution, I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: @SSS Precisely!

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm! And thanks for the good explanation!